# What are: TYPE, TYPES, TYPE-POOL, TYPE-POOLS and type group?

Tags: abap

I have found a few resources, but I am not sure if I understand.

Some of the resources I found are:

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/fc/eb2ff3358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm

http://basicsofabap.blogspot.com.tr/2009/04/type-groups.html

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-32630

Could you please help me with the keywords: `TYPE`, `TYPES`, `TYPE-GROUP`, `TYPE-POOL` ?

Where and why are they used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TYPE` is a keyword you use for example in `DATA` or `FIELD-SYMBOLS` declarations.

Examples

```
DATA lv_number TYPE i.

FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs_string> TYPE string.
```

`TYPES` is a keyword used for defining local types.

Examples

```
TYPES tt_numbers TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF char5 WITH DEFAULT KEY.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t_my_structure,
  id TYPE integer,
  comment TYPE string,
  END OF t_my_structure.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t_extended_t000,
  my_extension TYPE char5.
  INCLUDE TYPE t000.
TYPES END OF t_extended_t000.
```

`TYPE-POOL` is a grouping of locally defined types so you could use these types without duplication throughout many modules.

An example of a `TYPE-POOL` is the type group `ABAP`. Go to the transaction `SE11` and select Type Group and type `ABAP` there then press F7. You will see the body of the type group which is defined by the keyword `TYPE-POOL`.

You can use such a type group by importing it into your report by using `TYPE-POOLS` keyword.

Example

```
REPORT zzz.

TYPE-POOLS: abap.
```

Then you can use the types from this type group in you program `ZZZ`. I guess one could use an `INCLUDE` for such a purpose but this is definitely not recommended anymore.

I could not find a keyword `TYPE-GROUP` because it is highly probable that this is not a keyword at all. Type group is a synonym for a type pool.

Answer (score 1):

Type: is a keyword in Abap which is used to refer any built-in data types..
Types: is one of the keyword in Abap which is used to declare local data type..
Type-pool:is used for creating user defined data types.it is created in abap dictionary and can be used in all abap programs.type-pool must be the first definition in definition..
Type-Pools:it is used to access the type group in type-pool..such as SLIS is one of type group, to use it in our programm Type-Pools Slis will be used.